# sorl-thumbnail - cache folder

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm not able to get cache folder in my static directory.
When I not specify MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py file, cache folder is created on the root of my project and works well, but it is not his place.

If I configure MEDIA_ROOT to my static directory, no cache folder is created, nowhere, and rights are ok.

What did I miss ? Thanks.

Comment: I think its ut media root setting that is causing problem.  Trying something like this MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media').

Comment: I already tested with 'join' and with full path, same result..

Comment: Issue was due that my image (in upload dir) was not in the MEDIA_ROOT, it seems.. strange. Putting my upload dir in static dir resolve the problem.